# Wildfly looking in wrong directory

Tags: java, jboss, activiti, wildfly-8

I recently startet working with JBoss' Wildfly 8.1 and the activiti framework.

I created two projects, one with my bpmn.xml file and the classes for the Service Tasks:

```
Process:
 -src/main/
  -impl.java
 -src/resources/
  -diagrams
   -myprocess.bpmn.xml
  -config
   -activiti-context.xml
```

The other one holds the servlet

```
WebTest:
 -src/main
  -testServlet.java
 -lib
  -process.jar
```

in my servlet i implemented the init method to get the Activiti processEngine:

```
 @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException{
        super.init();
         engine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    }
```

I build the Webtest.war file and deploy it to

```
D:/path/to/workingdir/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/**standalone/deployments**/Webtest.war
```

Then i start up Widlfly using the provided standalone.bat, it starts up correctly and deploys to the context /Webtest, so far so good.

if i now access localhos:8080/Webtest/servlet i get the Exception:

org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't initialize process engine from spring configuration resource vfs:/D:/path/to/workingdir/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/**bin/content**/TEST-1.war/WEB-INF/**lib/process.jar/activiti-context.xml**: null

the error with :null at the end implies that the file could not be accessed. of course it cannot, there is no bin/content!

my question now is: where does Widlfly get the idea to look at bin/content? it obviously was able to find the config file on itself, i never told spring or activiti to look in the process.jar, so the app finds the configuration in the classpath alright... then it proceeds to reading the file from an entirely different location that does not exist?

I dont know if this is of interesst, but here is my activiti-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

      <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration"/>
</beans>
```

thanks for any help or hints!

Comment: Try to deploy your application unpacked, as folder. But as far as I know deployment on newest JBoss (Wildfly) is not supported by Activiti now.

Comment: Thanks, i will try. Do you happen to have a source that explicitly says JBoss 8 is not supported?